# A/an generator in c#

Tags: c#

Is there an framework supported way to generate 'a' or 'an' depending on the next word in C# (obviously for English)?

e.g.

```
var word = "stack";
Console.WriteLine( IndefiniteArticle( word ) + " " + word );
word = "overflow";
Console.WriteLine( IndefiniteArticle( word ) + " " + word );
```

to print

```
a stack
an overflow
```

Thanks
Tymek